# using org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager class in Java

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to use MEL functions inside my java class. I found that I can use org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager classe' evaluate method to accomplish this. I tried to implement this inside my onCall method but it doesn't seem to work for me. Is there a problem with the way DefaultExpressionManager is being used?

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext p_eventContext) throws Exception 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("reached inside onCall");
        MuleMessage l_receivedMsg = p_eventContext.getMessage();
        DefaultExpressionManager l_ExpressionManager = new DefaultExpressionManager();
    System.out.println("ServiceName==" +(String) l_ExpressionManager.evaluate("#[context:serviceName]", l_receivedMsg));
        return l_receivedMsg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use MEL directly from your code, you need to use the [ExpressionLanguage interface](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/el/ExpressionLanguage.html).

To get an instance of it, use:

```
ExpressionLanguage el = p_eventContext.getMuleContext().getExpressionLanguage();
```

Note that all the `evaluate` methods that accept a `MuleMessage` are deprecated. If this is a concern for you, then you'll have to change your component to become a custom `MessageProcessor` (ie. implement [org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/processor/MessageProcessor.html)). This will give you access to the `MuleEvent` from which you can get the `ExpressionLanguage` then call a non-deprecated `evaluate` method.

Also note that in your question `#[context:serviceName]` *is not a MEL expression*! You can learn about the MEL syntax there: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

Comment: getExpressionLanguage().evaluate(expression, MuleMessage) is deprecated as well!

Comment: Reviewed my answer based on your comment.

Comment: implementing org.mule.processor.MessageProcessor worked for me. Thanks David! Yes I am new to mule and trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating DefaultExpressionManager, do the following:

```
p_eventContext.getMuleContext().getExpressionManager();
```

Comment: Hi Seba,

I tried with
    
    getMuleContext().getExpressionManager().evaluate("#[context:serviceName]", l_receivedMsg))

though it works, i read that this method is now deprecated. I wonder then if this is the best way to move ahead!

Comment: Check the API of ExpressionManager for non-deprecated methods.

Comment: `ExpressionManager` is old. Prefer to use MEL and the `ExpressionLanguage`.